# Airflow push DAGs to localhost:8080

Tags: python, localhost, airflow

I've setup a standalone installation of Airflow on my device. I'm able to interact with the Airflow UI using localhost:8080. I followed this setup tutorial

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html

Next steps are for me to setup the pre-requisite files required for a project then once I have developed a project push the DAG etc... to the local server. I'm unsure how to do this?

My AIRFLOW_HOME directory is

C:\Users{user}\airflowhome

my project directory is

C:\Users{user}\PycharmProjects

Do I have to put my DAG files in the AIRFLOW_HOME directory?

Comment: Yes - you need to.

Comment: How do I setup separate projects?

Comment: Just point your pycharm project to dags dir.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - Airflow Does not support Windows as execution platform. You need to have WSL2 and run it on Linux Virtual machine (or in Docker container environment in Linux-based containers). So it is unlikely to work for you if you use Windows. Ther are some issues and PRs around this (https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16110 for example), but it's rather low priority.

But to answer your question: DAGs should be placed in dags_folder: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dags-folder